# Get all domains of a User and get all domains of the system in MAC OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, unix, active-directory, opendir

I need to find two things. My system is in a Domain network.

1. I need to find all the domains in which i can login.
2. All the domains that my current computer is affiliated with.

I've looked into OpenDirectyory framework of objective-C but didn't found much help.